# How to represent the loudness unit phon?

Tags: acoustics, units

We know that phon is the unit to measure the magnitude of loudness perceived.

But how to write the unit phone for example when we want to describe gram we use g(40 gram = 40g). Similarly, can anyone tell what is the symbol of the phon unit(40 phon= ?)?

Comment: In all the acoustic texts I have which use phons, the unit designator is "phon".

Comment: I think there aren't enough letters to give each unit a unique symbol that's less than 3 characters long. Another example is psi for pressure, which is already an acronym (pounds per square inch). What's it symbol? psi! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has already been answered in the comments (the answer is quite simple) but for completeness, I will provide an answer to be clearly visible.

There is no abbreviation in the unit of *phon*. The actual unit is *phon*, so when you want to declare the loudness of a measured quantity (most probably sound, I guess that makes sense) you declare $X ~ phon$ and that's it.

It is pretty much the same as with *bar*, which is a unit of pressure. There's no other way to right it, so when you declare a pressure in bars you right something like $Y ~ bar$. It is the same with the *phon*.